# Tailwindcss no custom amount classes

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm currently trying to use classes in Tailwind that contain {n} (e.g. grid-rows-{n}).
However, these classes are not written in my compiled css.

Tailwind Config:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
      "./dist/**/*.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

My Css file:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

My HTML File:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="p-3">

<div class="grid grid-rows-16 grid-cols-4">
    <div class="border-b border-black border-solid">
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="border-r border-black border-solid row-start-2">

    </div>
    <div class="border-b border-r border-black border-solid row-start-3">
        Test 2
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Command: `npx tailwindcss -i ./style.css -o ./dist/style.css --watch`

Everything except grid-rows-16 works.

Many thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As specified [here](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#all-variants-are-enabled), TailwindCSS classnames need to exist as complete strings for it to be compiled properly. As so, you cannot use `grid-rows-{n}`. You can, however, conditionally select the classname:

```
<div class={conditional === "whatever" ? 'grid-rows-8' : 'grid-rows-16'}>
```

Or use the style attribute:

```
<div style="grid-template-rows: {{ n }}"></div>
```

You haven't specified what framework you're using, but with React a potential solution with inline styles would be:

```
<div style={{
  gridTemplateRows: n
}}>
```

Comment: I think, you misunderstood me. As you can see in my example above, I use it unconditionally. But even then it won't compile.

Comment: Ohhh, I understand now. The problem is that the Tailwind grid template rows classnames only go up to 6: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-rows. Instead, you can use `<div style="grid-template-rows: 16;">`. Tell me if it solves your problem and I will update my answer (:

Comment: According to the Tailwind documentation, there should be a utility class that supports unlimited columns/rows

From there docs:
"Use the grid-cols-{n} utilities to create grids with n equally sized columns." (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#basic-usage)

Comment: Despite the fact that it says grid-cols-{n} it still is within the boundaries of that exact property. But it just struck me that you can actually just use arbitary values `class="grid-rows-[16]"`. Once again, please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: When i use this syntax, the compiled CSS looks like this: grid-template-rows: 16,
but it shoul be this: repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr)). I'm just a bit confused as the tailwind docs say it works

Comment: I suppose it makes sense that you should use the full syntax for arbitary values to maximize customizability. Just use `class="grid-rows-[repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))]"`. This has been a learning experience for me haha.